# save masked formatted value in data base

Tags: java

I have this insertion function :

```
public void insertInfo() throws Exception{
    try{
        int codeNat = getNat();

        String query = "INSERT INTO info (id,name,code_nat) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        stat = cnx.prepareStatement(query);
        stat.setString(1, txtId.getText());
        stat.setString(2, txtName.getText());//masked formatted field
        stat.setInt(3, codeNat);

        stat.execute();
        Update_table();

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }
    finally{
            stat.close();
    }
}
```

the field 'txtName' is a mask formatted text field, the fonction works but this field doesn't, like on the photo it's empty , when i change it to a simple text field it works, why?
the mask is :

```
JFormattedTextField txtName = new JFormattedTextField();
    mask = new MaskFormatter("########/##");
    mask.install(txtName);
```

[image]

Comment: So, your question doesn't actually have anything to do with saving something in a database, right? Also, you say "like on the photo it's empty", but it's not empty at all in the posted picture. What are you asking exactly? Post a *minimal* complete example reproducing the actual problem you have, tell us what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Where does the problem occure? are the values (names) not saved in the db or does the problem occure while displaying correctly stored and read from db date in the formattedTextField?

Comment: the field name is empty on the picture see from id 18 to 25 the corresponding name field is empty it haven't been saved